# How to access to other users' drives in a new OneDrive API for business?

Tags: office365, onedrive

I'm exploring a new OneDrive API for business, and can't find any solution for how to access other users' private files.

With old sharepoint API I could use specific endpoint url like this:

```
https://<org>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<user>_<org>_onmicrosoft_com/_api/v1.0/files/root/children
```

Now, I tried all of variations of

```
https://<org>-my.sharepoint.com/personal/<user>_<org>_sharepoint_com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children

https://<org>.sharepoint.com/personal/<user>_<org>_sharepoint_com/_api/v2.0/drive/root/children

https://<org>-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/personal/<user>_<org>_sharepoint_com/drive/root/children
```

And I get only 404 or 401: -2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException, Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

Is it even possible with new api?